# Adding variables to jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, variables, css-selectors

How can I add variables into my selectors :

```
function addCurrentClass(){
    var loc = window.location;
    $('#nav li a[href = "' + loc + '"]').addClass('currentpage');
}
```

I've tried many variations of the above using different types of selectors and can't get it to change to the value contained in var loc.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `window.location.href` rather than `window.location` to get the url, however the main problem with the approach is probably that it only works if you have fully qualified URLs in your link tags. Local or relative URLs won't work.

Comment: Thanks, working now, it's a rough approach I know, but can't do things properly serverside in this case. I guess I could use :contains(<?$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?>) ..hmm...

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
function addCurrentClass(){
    var loc = window.location.toString();
    $('#nav li a[href = "' + loc + '"]').addClass('currentpage');
}
```

I think you need to convert the `location` into string before you can get the string URL. Details are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).